# SpringData Pageable Projection with LeftJoin with JPA2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I have a project with 2.1.4.RELEASE with spring boot data.

The project has the following relation entities:
ApplicationEntity
ApplicationTranslateEntity
LanguageEntity

Its a locale relation tables in database (ManyToMany), with extra table for located text in different languages extra column in this table (ApplicationTranslateEntity).

**ApplicationEntity:**

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class ApplicationEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String urlImage;
    private String urlStoreiOS;
    private String urlStoreAndroid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "application")
    Set<ApplicationTranslationEntity> applicationTranslationEntities;

}
```

**ApplicationTranslateEntity:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ApplicationTranslationEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    ApplicationTranslationKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("application_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_id")
    ApplicationEntity application;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("language_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_id")
    LanguageEntity language;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String description;

}
```

**Projection:**

```
public interface ApplicationProjection {

    Long  getId();
    String getName();
    String getDescription();
    String getUrlImage();
    String getUrlStoreiOS();
    String getUrlStoreAndroid();
}
```

**Repository with Query:**

```
 @Query("select  a.id as id, a.urlImage as urlImage, at.name as name, at.description as description  from ApplicationEntity a left join a.applicationTranslationEntities at on at.language.key = :language")
Page<ApplicationProjection> findAllByLanguage(Pageable pageable, Language language);
```

**Rest Controller Application:**

```
 @GetMapping()
Page<ApplicationDto> all(Pageable pageable, @RequestHeader(value= headerAcceptEncoding, required = false) Language language){
    return applicationService.findAll(pageable,language);
}
```

All work fine with pagination and sort with id. But when I try to sort by name which is on ApplicationTranslationEntities, I saw that hibernate try to make sort in ApplicationEntity not in ApplicationTranslateEntity.
Why did this happen?

The error is:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: ******entity.ApplicationEntity [select a.id as id, a.urlImage as urlImage, a.urlStoreiOS as urlStoreiOS, a.urlStoreAndroid as urlStoreAndroid,  at.name as name, at.description as description from ******.entity.ApplicationEntity a left join a.applicationTranslationEntities at on at.language.key = :language order by a.id asc, a.name asc]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: ******.entity.ApplicationEntity [select a.id as id, a.urlImage as urlImage, a.urlStoreiOS as urlStoreiOS, a.urlStoreAndroid as urlStoreAndroid,  at.name as name, at.description as description from *******.entity.ApplicationEntity a left join a.applicationTranslationEntities at on at.language.key = :language order by a.id asc, a.name asc]

Comment: What is the pagination property you are using to build Pageable?? In other works show how you are creating Pageable

Comment: I edit the question, I use the `import org.springframework.data.domain.Page` and I didn´t change nothing in Pageable.

Comment: Fine but i still dont know what params did you use for pagination. It contains property name. And that is what i am interested about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using pagination property of `name` while it should be (idk which one is the proper one) either `applicationTranslationEntities.name` (property path) or `a.name` (as per join path).

Comment: Works fine with at.name thanks, I can do something to change this?

Comment: But why do you want to change that?

Comment: I want to change name parameter  with sort in page, use the name of field without alias of database, because if I change something in query maybe users cant use this sort field

Comment: Well then you will have to map column names from view to column names used in query by yourself.